RSYSLOG not picking up files named as dates yymmdd
Rsyslog on older OS nodes of Ubuntu 14.04 not picking up logs located on NFS generated as date.
rsyslogd 7.4.4, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    FEATURE_LARGEFILE:          No
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Ye

I am trying to pull in logs from NFS into syslog using an imfile.
The files are in date format for yymmdd
230629 230802  230905  231009  231112  231216  240119  240222  240327

My imfile looks like this:
note it is defined in another file module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
Also I have other imfile logs that are in a .log format that are working fine on this node.
    input(type="imfile"
          File="/nfs/data/logs/run_auto_renew_LOG/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
          Tag="run_auto_renew_log:"
          StateFile="statefile-run_auto_renew_log_log"
          Severity="info"
          Facility="local7")

rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 7.4.4, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.

I am expecting the logs to show up in syslog.
I have tried several iterations such as:
File="/nfs/data/logs/run_auto_renew_LOG/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
File="/nfs/data/logs/run_auto_renew_LOG/$([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
I have also tried setting up templates:
# Define a template for the log file paths
$template DailyLogFilePath,"/nfs/data/logs/run_auto_renew_LOG/%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%"

# Use the template in the imfile input
input(type="imfile"
      File="%DailyLogFilePath%"
      Tag="run_auto_renew_log"
      StateFile="statefile-run_auto_renew_log_log"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local7")

